# Ear ossicles a part of Skull?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, hearing, human-ear

Is there anything special about not considering ear ossicles as a part of skull?

I could not understand the reasoning behind such  classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The justification is simple.

The bones of the ear [ear ossicles] do not articulate with any other bone of the skull hence it is not considered as a part of the skull, similar is the case with the hyoid which is attached to the tongue.These bones have been placed under the group of associated bones.